# Unable to insert pulled data from an API into SQL Server database

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, api, pyodbc

I am trying to pull JSON data from Python retrieved via an API with access token needed into SQL Server database.

The table format is as follows:

```
                  [dbo].[Products](

                               [ProductName] [varchar](50) NULL,
                               [ProductDesc] [varchar](50) NULL,
                               [ProductAmount] [int] NULL
                          )
```

I am able to access the data from the API using the below query:

```
 import requests

TOKEN = Token_key

BASE_URL = '[url]'

HEADERS = 
        {

       'Authorization': TOKEN

        }

data = {
        "query" : {
            "dimensions" : [
            "ProductName";
            "ProductDesc"
            ],
            "measures": [
             "ProductAmount"
            ]
           }
         }
            
    response = requests.get('[url]', headers=HEADERS, json=data)

    print(response.json())
```

I am trying to insert the dimension and measure values received from the API into the table above which is on SQL Server 2016 database using pyodbc as seen below:

```
import pyodbc

   conn = 
                pyodbc.connect ('Driver={SQL Server};'

                     'Server=Servername;'

                    'Database=Databasename;'

                    'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

SQLCommand = ("INSERT INTO [Tablename] 
                  (ProductName, ProductDesc, ProductAmount) 
                VALUES (?,?,?);")

 Values = ['$.ProductName', '$.ProductDesc', '$.ProductAmount']

cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)

 conn.commit()
```

The INSERT command is only inserting the text $.ProductName, $.ProductDesc and $.ProductAmount as seen below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV8uY.png)

into the table but would like to insert the values retrieved.

The answer could be similar to [Issue with inserting data into Sql server using Python Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613955/issue-with-inserting-data-into-sql-server-using-python-pandas-dataframe) but this is a POST as opposed to GET and limited with my Python knowledge.

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I realised I misread your question anyway.

Comment: You're populating the `Values` array with the strings `'$.ProductName'`, `'$.ProductDesc'` and `'$.ProductAmount'` so of course that's what it's going to insert into the table. I'm guessing those are meant to be paths into your JSON response, so have you tried adding some code to extract the corresponding values from your JSON response? Start by reading the [json - JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning. I ended up extracting the values onto a json file using json_string = json5.dumps(data). Then, I intend using SSIS to load the contents into SQL Server.